# Max Results symfony2 dql

Tags: symfony, dql

I have some problem with my database query. I need to set max results, but when i'm doing that i don't have result what i expected. (eg. when i have 2 "hashtags" decreases by one)
Here is code:

```
$r = $this->createQueryBuilder("q")
        ->select("q AS image, sb, hs")
        ->addSelect("c, SUM(CASE WHEN (c.likeCount!=false) THEN c.likeCount ELSE 0 END) AS likes")
        ->addSelect("cm, COUNT(cm) AS comments")
        ->addSelect("u, SUM(CASE WHEN (c.user=:user) THEN c.likeCount ELSE 0 END) AS userLiked")
        ->leftJoin("q.siteBox","sb")
        ->leftJoin("q.imageLikes","c")
        ->leftJoin("q.hashtags","hs")
        ->leftJoin("q.comments","cm")
        ->setMaxResults(4)
        ->leftJoin("c.user","u")
        ->setParameter("user",$user)
        ->groupBy("hs.id,q.id")
        ->orderBy("q.date","DESC")
    ;
```

Sorry for my bad english, but i wthink everybody will understand.

Comment: try putting setMaxResults as last statement

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it doesn't work, but i were fixed it by using Paggination from  DQL